# how multiple automation testers work in same selenium project

Tags: selenium, integration, environment

We are three testers and going to prepare automation project with selenium and java  code so what are the steps for environment setup , scripts integration and running the testcases and getting the results for the whole project suits

Answer (score 2):

So there are a few things we have to use in order to allow multiple engineers to work on the same framework.

Step 1) Creating the framework, assuming you know how to do this already, you have working tests you can skip this stage, however if not please follow the tutorial i link below.

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/

Step 2) Creating a REPO, my preference is GitHub, you can use any git repo however i will post the guide to set one up with GitHub, its a similar process for all. This will allow you to merge code properly without causing conflicts.

https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/

Step 3) Source Control program - to push, pull and fetch from your GitHub Repo, you can do this from Command Prompt however i find cloning the repo into a program like 'SourceTree' is really easy, so i've posted that below.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/get-started-with-sourcetree

If you follow these 3 guides, you will be able to have your automation test scripts on GitHub by the end of the day.

If you have any more questions please do not hesitate to ask.

All the best, Jack

Comment: Thanks Jack for your help but the company environment working with Microsoft products so it will be difficult to use GitHub , is there source control in Microsoft that could push /pull code on ?

Comment: Hi there, there are many different options for you to use

https://stackify.com/source-code-repository-hosts/

If you check this list i believe its 50 different repo hosts =] i hope this helps

Comment: Microsoft technically own GitHub now, as of June 2018. You could also go with TFS (Team Foundation Server) - Microsoft's own source-control that is built into Visual Studio as part of the package. TFS can he hosted locally in your own network so you can control all of your code, privately. I would recommend purchasing a private GitHub account, as I believe it's Microsoft's intention to keep on developing GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most logical way to do this would be to create one branch in your CVS (git or SVN, etc) and have each person setup the dev environment in the same way. Work exactly like developers and pull code before you check-in/commit (this will ensure that one small error does not break your framework) and swear to resolve conflicts during merge (to ensure you don't step on each others' toes).
Also, before you kick off, agree on a standard of coding (including package naming, design pattern usage, filename and methodname usage) and if this is in sync with the dev coding standards in your company, even better.
There will be a few hiccups along the way, but experience is the best way to create a process for your development and check-in practices.

Good luck with your new project and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You have asked two questions, in my opinion the answer of your questions is.

1. how multiple automation testers work in same selenium project - You can use any version control system, Git Hub is the best option which gives you a lot of facilities. You all three can work on same project at same time or you can go for any centralized version control system like tortoise svn which is not much likely used now a days. I will suggest Git Hub for that.
2. what are the steps for environment setup , scripts integration and running the test cases and getting the results for the whole project suits - It depends on various factors like application and the kind of framework you want to use, there are many frameworks which are widely used for automation testing like Modular Framework, Data Driven, Keyword Driven, BDD, Cucumber, TestNg etc or if you have bandwidth and time you can design your custom framework as per the needs.

I hope I put some glimpse on your queries.

Thanks